# Why does Shell of an exe file not work if it is on the desktop?

Tags: excel, vba, shell

As an example, if I `Shell` notepad.exe in its native location it works as expected and I can access it via `AppActivate`. But if I copy notepad.exe to a desktop folder, `Shell` returns an apparently valid PID but notepad doesn't start. Subsequent `AppActivate` fails with runtime error 5 - Invalid procedure call or argument, presumably because there is no Notepad process.
(Note - I need the `vPID` from `Shell` to kill any previous notepad processes.)

Following code illustrates, swap comment between the two `ExeLocation` assignments.

```vb
Sub RunNotepad()
    Dim ExeLocation As String
    Dim x As String
    Dim vPID As Variant
            
    'ExeLocation = "C:\windows\system32\notepad.exe"                '  Option A
    ExeLocation = "C:\Users\Dell User\Desktop\Temporary\notepad.exe" ' Option B

    x = Dir(ExeLocation)
    Debug.Print x                ' Prints notepad.exe for A & B
           
    vPID = Shell(ExeLocation, vbMaximizedFocus) 'Returns a vPID value for A & B
    AppActivate (vPID)           ' Option A fine, option B fails
End Sub
```

See above code.  I expected Option B to work the same as Option A

Comment: Do you *copy* Notepad.exe or do you create a Shortcut? When I copy Notepad.exe to my desktop, I cannot start it at all.

Comment: Notepad is not a stand-alone executable. You also need to copy one other support file. See 
 https://superuser.com/questions/279031/copy-notepad-exe-from-system-folder-to-desktop-and-run-it